# Adding Index via HTTP Get in Apache SOLR

Tags: solr

I have a problem using SOLR when add document via GET method :

http://localhost:8983/solr/update?stream.body=%3Cadd%3E%3Cdoc%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22office%22%3EBridgewater%3C/field%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22skills%22%3EPerl%3C/field%3E%3Cfield%20name=%22skills%22%3EJava%3C/field%3E%3C/doc%3E%3C/add%3E

The error I got is

> HTTP ERROR 400
>
> Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
>
> ERROR: [doc=null] unknown field 'office'

Is there any prerequisite that I'd missed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in the `schema.xml` you don't have the definition for the `office` field. If you have it, maybe you're using the wrong case to refer to it?

Comment: Hi Javanna, should I have all predefined fields first in schema.xml ? As I have understood so far, schema.xml is only for data import handler, CMIIW.

Comment: @Dino [`schema.xml`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml) is where you list all the fields you have, it doesn't matter if you use dih to import data or you submit documents "manually" (the dih does the same internally). So, yes, you should define all your fields in you schema.xml

Comment: Hi Javanna, yes.. the fields defined in schema.xml solved it. Thank you very much for this :)